# Using Sling Taglib version 1.3 in a CQ5.6.1 project

Tags: jsp, maven, aem, taglib, sling

I've been reading this article http://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/sling-scripting-jsp-taglib.html on the new Sling Taglib version 1.3 as I want to start using the new JSTL functions like listChildren, so that I can avoid Java scriptlets in my components.

When I use the taglib declaration

```
<%@taglib prefix="sling" uri="http://sling.apache.org/taglibs/sling" %>
```

in my component JSP, when I put the component into my PARSYS I get the following error

```
org.apache.sling.api.scripting.ScriptEvaluationException:
org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.JasperException:
The absolute uri: http://sling.apache.org/taglibs/sling cannot be resolved
in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
```

In my maven pom.xml file I have the dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.taglib</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

And the project builds correctly and installs correctly.

Does anyone know how to configure a CQ 5.6.1 project to use Sling Taglib Version 1.3 Bundle Version 2.2.0 with URI `http://sling.apache.org/taglibs/sling`?

Answer (score 4):

CQ 5.6.1 contains `org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.taglib` bundle in version 2.1.8 (which defines taglib in version 1.2). In order to use the new taglib, you need to upgrade the bundle.

If you define a Maven dependency as `provided` it means that it's already installed on the target platform. In this case it isn't true. Remove the scope or change it to `compile` in order to include the new taglib bundle to the CQ package. After package installation you can use all new features.

You may also install [the bundle](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/sling/org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.taglib/2.2.0/org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.taglib-2.2.0.jar) manually (via Felix console) - you won't need any Maven dependencies then.

Please notice that CQ may become unresponsive after installing new taglib bundle. Restarting instance should help.